# Slide an image using only css

Tags: html, css, animation

What was the earlier option to slide an image sideways (2d) before we started using jquery or CSS3 to do so ?

This was a HTML option of some sort ?

I am trying to teach some sudents about early ethods vs modern methods.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could someone perhaps take a look at this and tell me if anything still needs changing so the question isn't opinion based anymore ? (I think it's okay now, but am not sure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do any of you guys remember this property ?

The [marquee element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0) (marked as obsolete in HTML 5).

> Any info about this method as to why people don't use it

Scrolling text is hard to read at the best of times. When you start trying to read it after the start of it has scrolled off the screen, doubly so.

Comment: Thanks ! (With your second answer: I meant using it for pictures of courrse rather than text) But I can see that the options are clearly way less varied so that's propably why :)